# How to create a button to close active session in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, session, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I need to create a button to log out in Joomla, I mean, the user usually enter the session but then must press the button I created to close this session, I know how to check if any user has entered the session and I know how to display the button, what I don't know is how to make that button close the actual user session (log out).

This is the base code I have:

```
<?php $user =& JFactory::getUser(); ?>
<?php if ( ($user->id)==0 ) : ?>

    //***code for not opened session***

<?php else : ?>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Close Session" />
    </form>

<?php endif ?>
```

How to make that button to close the joomla 2.5 session, I checked the API page but i didn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this link -

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?index.php?option=com_user&task=user.logout&token=<?php echo JUtility::getToken(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, although the link did not work (Joomla 404 message), I managed to make it work like this:
 <input class="button" type="submit" value="Finalizar sesión" name="Submit">
 <input type="hidden" value="com_users" name="option">
 <input type="hidden" value="user.logout" name="task">   
 <input type="hidden" value="1" name="<?php echo JUtility::getToken(); ?>">

Answer (score 7):

To create a log out button, you could create a link with the class "button".

In Joomla > 1.7 (also 2.5.x) you need the JUtility::getToken() part to make the login successful: Use the optional "return" part for redirecting the user back to the page where the user was when clicking the button

```
<a class="button" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&'. JUtility::getToken().'=1'); ?>">
    Logout
</a>
```

If you want to redirect back to the page where the user was when he/she clicked the logout button, add a base64 encoded return parameter:

```
<a class="button" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&'. JUtility::getToken().'=1&return='.base64_encode(JURI::current())); ?>">
    Logout
</a>
```

Comment: For Joomla 3, you need to use JSession::getFormToken() instead of JUtility::getToken()

Answer (score 4):

the correct link is actually

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&'. JUtility::getToken() .'=1');
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works for joomla 2.5. I swapped JURI::current() with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] from @Beatniak code

```
<a class="button" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&'. JUtility::getToken().'=1&return='.base64_encode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>">
    Logout
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

u may try also this for Joomla 2.5

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_users&task=user.logout&<?php echo JUtility::getToken(); ?>=1">
<input  type="button" name="Submit" class="button" value="Logout">
</a>
```

works good for me

Answer (score 0):

Link to a php page

```
<a href="/link.php">Sign Out</a>
```

On the php page, simply end the session, then redirect to a new page.

```
<?php
    session_destroy();   //session is now over


    header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/welcomepage.php' ) ; //relink to a page, with user logged out

?>
```

User is now logged out, and redirected to the welcome page

Comment: Thank, one question, session_destroy just close the current session or closes all the sesions?

Comment: session_destroy only closes the session for the specific users session. Not everyone elses.

Comment: Just to let you know Elassar, since you are a newbie, if an answer is answered correctly, please use the check box to the left of the answer to accept it.  Cheers

Comment: +1 because it's a quick and dirty way. It has it's costs though, you loose all session variables from that particularly session client when you session_destroy();. Also in order to execute that code you must have it in some other controller file which ads some effort to the final solution when the same solution can be established with another simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

With Joomla 2.5 you need to make a new menu item titled Logout and choose the menu type to be the User Manager - Login Form.

By doing this if the user is logged in then this will take them to a page with a logout button instead of the login form.

Also if you set the access permissions to only display this logout menu item for registered users.

This was a very easy solution to do without any coding knkowledge.
Really there should be a menu item option for the user manager - logout.